# This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am having this problem using Jsoup in Eclipse. I have attached the following jar files: 
jsoup 1.7.2.jar
jsoup 1.7.2.javadoc.jar
jsoup 1.7.2.sources.jar
I have added these jar files as external jar files in the configuration path and have linked them to the C:\USERS drive where I stored the files. The program has no errors but when I run it I get the NullPointerException error on this line "Element gameElement = firstLottoRow.child(1);" or any other line of code like this that is using Jsoup to parse HTML from the URL. 
I am getting the "element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found" with the line of code: "Element tbody = table.getElementsByTag("tbody").first();"

Am I doing everything right in terms of my configuration path linking to the jsoup jar files, or could anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong?
Thanks so much for any help!

Here is the Jsoup code:

```
private LotteryDraw extractLotteryDraw(String html) {


        LotteryDraw lotteryDraw = new LotteryDraw();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("drawhistory");
        //System.out.println(elements.toString());
        Element table = elements.first();
        Element tbody = table.getElementsByTag("tbody").first();
        Element firstLottoRow = tbody.getElementsByClass("lottorow").first();

        Element dateElement = firstLottoRow.child(0);
        System.out.println(dateElement.text());

        Element gameElement = firstLottoRow.child(1);
        System.out.println(gameElement.text());

        Element noElement = firstLottoRow.child(2);
        System.out.println(noElement.text());
        String[] split = noElement.text().split(" - ");

        int[] numbers = new int[split.length];

        int i = 0;
        for (String strNo : split) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.valueOf(strNo);
            i++;
        }

        lotteryDraw.setNumbers(numbers);
        Log.v("DEBUG", "the value of numbers is " + numbers);
        Element bonusElement = firstLottoRow.child(3);
        Integer bonusBall = Integer.valueOf(bonusElement.text());

        lotteryDraw.setBonusBall(bonusBall);
        Log.v("DEBUG", "the value of numbers is " + numbers);
        return lotteryDraw;
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding the src and javadoc jar files as external jar attach them to the jar with the classes as source or javadoc attachment.

Right click on the library jar and select "Properties". In the dialog that opens specify the location of the source and/or javadoc jar.

Comment: Sorry so this still isnt working. I went to the jsoup 1.7.2. javadoc.jar file under referenced libs, right clicked it brought me to a screen headed Java Source Attachment asks to select location of (folder/jar/zip) I selected external location as thats where I have it stored, in the C:\ drive. when I chose workspace location I wasnt able to locate it as its not there. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Click on "External File ..." and select the jar you want to attach.

Comment: i did the jar is in the libs folder but it still not recognised

Comment: Try to restart Elipse

Comment: I tried this. I saved my applications, closed eclipse, went into the C:\ drive copied jar files in question directly into the libs folder under the workspace folder for my application, opened Eclipse again and I have a red exclamation mark on every project folder that I have been developing, apart from the one that I am currently having this problem with. I have no idea why this has happened. The other projects dont have errors in the program but when I try to run it, it says theres errors that need fixed. My problems have really escalated now!

Comment: Thanks for your advice though @Henry I do appreciate it, especially as I am new to the software development field!

Comment: The other projects use these jars as well? Otherwise this seems to be an unrelated problem.